# Access ROS command-line tools via Java

Tags: rosnode, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to write a tool for ROS which allows the user to combine Eclipse with PyDev. Therefore, I want to create an eclipse plugin.

I am trying for quite some time to access the commandline tools like "rosnode" in Java but I am not yet able to accomplish it. Is there anyone who already accomplished that and could give me some ideas how to manage it. Is there a package or some junks of code as an example?

Until now I tried it as a direct process, as a shell script, and jython (but this is not 100% out).

Any Idea would be great. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9411/access-ros-command-line-tools-via-java/) by [Chakka](https://answers.ros.org/users/289/chakka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's great to hear you are working on an Eclipse plugin.  If you access it as a process, have you made sure to pass in ROS_ROOT, ROS_MASTER_URI, and ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?  The tools will not function without those set.

In the long run, a lot of the information would be easier to get access to by writing XML-RPC clients that talk to the master, which is how tools like rosnode and rosparam get most of their information.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1